# Pass an ENV variable to docker run

Tags: docker, heroku, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm trying to deploy a docker image to heroku, heroku don't let you specify a port in the **Dockerfile**, they will pass the port with a command like `docker run -p 80:$PORT -e PORT=$PORT`, But how can I use the passed variable in the Dockerfile, Here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app


# install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libsndfile1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg

RUN useradd -m -u 1000 user
USER user

ENV HOME=/home/user \
    PATH=/home/user/.local/bin:$PATH

WORKDIR $HOME/app

COPY --chown=user . $HOME/app

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "${PORT}"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variable substitution in a command is done by the shell.

When you use the *exec* form of CMD, there's no shell to do the substitution.

Use the *shell* form of CMD instead and there will be a shell to do it. Like this

```
CMD uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port ${PORT}
```